# Can't build any project in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've installed VS 2015 community with Xamarin. I can't build a new android project even I didn't add any thing ,simply it is new project.
the error message as shown in photo.
did lots of search but still couldn't figure out what leads to this error.

-there are some answer for this question before which I've gone through them and they don't work to fix this issue.

any help is appreciated.[The Error List in VS 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZxQc.png)

Answer (score 1):

aapt.exe can crash if any of your images or other resource contains "-" or " ". To avoid crash remove those symbols. See more details see this question on Xamarin forums: [Build fails on Android projects - "appt.exe" exited with code 1073741816](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11311/build-fails-on-android-projects-appt-exe-exited-with-code-1073741816)

If that does not help you may need to reinstall Visual Studio and Xamarin: 
[“aapt.exe” exited with code -1073741819](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564002/aapt-exe-exited-with-code-1073741819)

Comment: thank you for your replay . even for new project I can't build it and the resource contain only icon.png.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: "aapt" is Android Asset Packaging Tool.

Increase your MSBuild output verbosity in order to get more details on what is causing the failure:

- MSBuild project build output verbosity to Diagnostic

> Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build And Run then find where it says MSBuild project build output verbosity (on Visual Studio 2015 that’s a dropdown) and change it from Minimal to Normal or Diagnostic if it isn’t set to that option already.

Clean and Rebuild your app and review the contents of Build Output window.

**Note: Usually `aapt` errors revolve around resources with "bad names", spaces, invalid characters, etc...**

**Note: SDK Build Tools 21.0.x has some bugs with `aapt`, open your Android SDK Manager and make sure that you have the latest installed:**

[image]

In my case, I have the latest 23 installed (plus a few older versions required for some Android Studio projects).

If you need to change which version Android SDK build-tools is being used to avoid SDK bugs/issues on various Windows OS versions, you can set the `AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion` MSBuild Property.

> AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion
>
> The Android SDK build-tools package provides the `aapt` and `zipalign` tools, among others. Multiple different versions of the build-tools package may be installed simultaneously.
>
> ~~~
>
> default value may be overridden within youur project file to choose an alternate build-tools version, if (for example) the latest aapt is crashing out while a previous aapt version is known to work.

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/

Comment: @Mustafa.Jumma You only get three lines in your build output with Diagnostic verbosity?

Comment: these are the lines which show the error

Comment: @Mustafa.Jumma Which version(s) of Android SDK Build-Tools to you have installed?

Comment: @Mustafa.Jumma What about the "Build-tools" version(s), you are listing your SDK tools and platform-tools version

Comment: The build tool is 23.0.1

Answer (score 0):

The issue solved after I tried many things but the one which work with me is that 
 1.Uninstall Android SDK.
 2.Manually remove any folders related to Android (Which I haven't done before).
 3.Reinstall Android SDK.
thanks for your help.